# Andengine getLastChild() error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es, andengine

I get the following error while i run the andengine activity

> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   method getLastChild()   location:
>   variable scene of type org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene

i have included all the andengine jar files and added it as a refernced library.Please help. Is this method redundant now? If so are there any alternatives for that? Or is it because i develop my games on a computer which doesnt have graphics. I have developed many apps for android. But i am having problems with this andengine game development.Please help. Here is the code block that has the error.

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    final Scene scene = new Scene(1);
    final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion);
    scene.getLastChild().attachChild(splash);
    return scene;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You are instantiating a `Scene` with a deprecated constructor:

[image: Capture from official library source]

2- If you simply want to add a `Sprite` into a `Scene` change your code for this:

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    final int centerX =
            (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int centerY =
            (CAMERA_HEIGHT -
                    this.mSplashTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX,
            centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion);
    scene.attachChild(splash);
    return scene;
}
```

3- If, on the other hand, what you want to do is to attach a `Sprite` as a child of another `Entity`, simply hold a reference of the parent `Entity` where you'll attach other childs, before or after it is added to the `Scene` (it doesn't matter).